# Jquery Ajax hitting error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Jquery ajax code which works on some website and same code don't work when i use on other website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check_domain( d, e){

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php?domain=" + d,
                success: function(data){

                    var ele = $("." + e);

                    ele.find("td.td_emails").html(data);


                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error occurs!');
                }
        });
    }
</script>
```

i am calling this function in html like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">check_domain("http%3A%2F%2Fwww.1smile.co.uk%2F", "tr_12");</script>
```

But it go to ajax error function rather going to success function on some domains and on other it works fine. Please point out the error.

Comment: Your browser will point out the error. Have you done your debugging? Network tab show anything? Things we need to know!

Comment: Network Tab showing 403 forbidden

Comment: Ok found the issue. I was encoding urls with urlencode php function i have replaced it with base64_encode. now it is working fine.